# c++ libcurl and SSL setup for https read file

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, https, libcurl

For my desktop sofware (Windows 7 - 10) I check version with read file on server and get information from it (read txt file). This is done, but i am not sure if I use SSL right setup and If need security for that simple thing (I am not sure how SSL works, I used some example from libcurl examples). I only read txt file and get information (program version) and that is all.

Maybe worth to mention, I use binaries from libcurl download site for Windows (binary   the curl project).

Here is portion of code how I use libcurl:

```
std::stringstream isf;
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
/* CURL functions are function pointers because I load libcurl manually (LoadLibrary()) */
curl = curlEasyInit();
if (curl)
{
    curlEasySetOpt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/MyFile.txt");
    curlEasySetOpt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_read_stream);
    curlEasySetOpt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &isf);

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // *** Question below ***
    curlEasySetOpt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
    curlEasySetOpt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L); // this is needed if I use CURLOPT_USE_SSL othervise it is unable to connect to https if I use CURLOPT_USE_SSL
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    res = curlEasyPerform(curl);
    // ...
    curlEasyCleanup(curl);
    curlGlobalCleanup();
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

---

```
size_t my_read_stream(void * buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * stream)
{
    bool ok = false;
    size_t b;
    try {
        std::stringstream * fs = static_cast<std::stringstream *>(stream);
        b = size * nmemb;
        fs->write(static_cast<char*>(buffer), b);
        ok = true;
    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR READ STREAM : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    if (ok)
    {
        return b;
    }
    else
    {
        b = size * nmemb;
        return b;
    }
}
```

---

Questions:

I am able to connect `https://example.com/MyFile.txt` and read file without SSL setup (see code encapsulated with comment). When I used `curlEasySetOpt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);` I am not able connect to https site because verification failed (need some certification) and when I turn of `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, I am able connect to https, now questions are:

1. Is this SSL setup (in code I provided) enough secure for that read
   file?
2. when I use this SSL setup does it add some security?
3. does this simple read file code need a SSL security, when I use
   https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling SSL certificate validation opens you up to man/monster in the middle attacks. It only encrypts traffic for people who are passively intercepting your communication. Either get a commercial verifiable certificate, a free one from Let's encrypt, or a self-signed certificate where you explicitly trust the CA you used.

After going back and forth in the comments, it seems that your curl is missing its root CA bundle. This bundle is used to validate all SSL certificates. Take  `curl-ca-bundle.crt` from the libcurl package and put it next to your program. You may need to set the [CURLOPT_CAINFO option](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html) to point to that file before curl can use it as certificate bundle.

As for the last question, that is up to your threat model. A MitM attack allows all of the following:

- Are you okay with people intercepting the contents of the file? (confidentiality)
- Can your program survive arbitrary changes to the file? (file corruption, replay attacks and possible exploits)
- Can your program survive arbitarily large files? (DoS)

Comment: I use LetsEncrypt on my website. I am not sure how it is working, but my host provide it automatically, therefore I am not sure if I understand, but how I obtain that certificate (LE) and use it in libcurl? Btw. my file contain only number of latest program version. That all, I think this is not secret or confidentiality.

Comment: If your web server is configured correctly the certificate should be marked as validated without effort from you.

Comment: I think web server is configured correctly, on webbrowser it uses https without problem.

Comment: Check what is happening by setting the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option.

Comment: with that option I got this error description: Trying xx.xxx.xxx.xx:443...
Connected to example.com (xx.xxx.xxx.xx) port 443 (#0)
ALPN, offering h2
ALPN, offering http/1.1
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Closing connection 0
curl told us 60

Comment: I tested it with `https://www.google.com` link and I got same error. But when I change https to http then it connect to link. Therefore I think something wrong is with libcurl.

Comment: Did you download a build that uses OpenSSL? If so, you may need to properly configure/update the certificate store (ca bundle) and point libcurl to it..

Comment: I use binaries from libcurl download site for Windows (binary the curl project). And they use OpenSSL

Comment: If I understand, that ca budnle must be included with my software or somwhere on my website?

Comment: with your software, yes.

Comment: I just checked the download: there is a `curl-ca-bundle.crt` in the `bin` folder. You need to [put it next to your binary file or somewhere else on the PATH](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) (see step 4 of "certificate verification")

Comment: I have this file in bin, unfortunately wherever I add the file, it can't connect to https. Maybe I have to load *.crt file manually (from code)? Btw, step 4 is for comindline tool not code with libcurl.dll if I understand correctly.

Comment: It should probably be right next to your program. Also see the edit to my answer about that CAINFO option.

Comment: Thanks! Now it is working, I can connect to my https link without disabled CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.